# How to ensure that object is ALWAYS allocated on stack in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Possible solution to me overload new operator and make it private so that prevents you from calling new operator.

**But lets say even with new called I want object to be allocated on stack . Is it possible ?**

Comment: What is the use-case for this?

Comment: You can overload `operator new` so it uses a memory pool on the stack.

Comment: There's no "stack" in C++. A type cannot generally control the storage duration of its instances. (E.g. consider global variables.)

Comment: FYI there is nothing about stack space in standard C++.  Objects are separated into automatic and dynamic objects.

Comment: XY problem or just general curiousness?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth & n.m No use-case just curiosity 
Not able to understand statement no concept of stack in C++ memory model :(  If I create object without new where object will reside. I am sure its not on heap. 
Any link to understand the concept of no stack in C++ would be appreciated.

Comment: @NoName "No stack in C++" means that the C++ standard does not concern itself with things like "stack" or "heap." Objects have automatic, static, dynamic, or thread *storage duration.* On most implementations, dynamic ones go on the heap. Automatic ones go on the stack (local variables), or wherever their containing object is (members). Static ones go into some global memory segment usually. But that's an *implementation of C++* thing. C++ itself prescribes how e.g. automatic and dynamic storage duration must behave, and leaves it up to the implementation to arrange that.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling up the comments into some kind of answer:

> But lets say even with new called I want object to be allocated on stack . Is it possible ?

Strictly speaking there is no concept of a stack in the c++ memory model, but let's assume you mean "disallow an object from being dynamically allocated".

The short answer is "no, it's not possible to prevent it". Even convoluted tricks with custom `new` do not help you.

Although this might seem like a frustrating answer, it's actually a good thing. The functionality of an object is a separate concern to its lifetime and storage location. Allowing the object to dictate it's lifetime mixes the two concerns and makes the object less useful.

If you want to dynamically allocate objects on the stack in order to increase (or guarantee) performance, then you will want to create a custom allocator for that job. i.e. the custom allocator can contain a block of memory into which models of your class can be in-place constructed.

Andrei Alexandrescu gave a good talk on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U